# How to create a directory of event participants with custom fields?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, reports

I want to create something that would allow someone to enter an event id (ideally multiple event IDs), and generate a report that includes participant fields that I choose.

What I have in mind is something similar to a directory, that shows name/location/employer of all the participants of a chosen event.

Is this best done through creating a report, or by creating a standalone form?

Comment: if your CMS is drupal then Views could be on your list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 'someone' that needs to access the information is an administrator then you could set up a report to do this using 'Reports > Event reports > Event participants list. In the 'Columns' you can select the fields (including standard and custom fields) to display. In the 'Filter's you can specify which events to display participants for - which is something that your admins can change.

The documentation for using the reports for CiviEvents can be found here:
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/events/reports/

This is an approach that's built in to Civi. But there are of course other solutions, such as using Drupal's Views module to expose the information (as suggested in the comments). This could be useful if you wanted to expose the information to end users.